# Find non-root parent node where child contains some text

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I have some xml;

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>foo987654</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>bar15245</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>baz87742</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>foo123456</child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

I'm using python and the etree module and I'd like to select all `<parent>` nodes whose child starts with "foo".  I know etree has limited xpath support but i'm an xpath rookie so I'm struggling to land on the best solution.   I'd think something to this effect

```
parent[(contains(child,'foo'))]
```

but i would want to reject parent nodes that contained foo but didn't start with foo (ie `<child>125456foo</child>`) so i'm not sure this would work.  Furthermore, I'm not sure etree supports this level of xpath...

EDIT:

Another acceptable solution would be to to select parents whose children's text are in a list. 
pseudo code 
parent=>child[text = "foo1" || "bar1" || "bar2"]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get what you want:

```
[elem for elem in root.findall('parent') if elem.find('child').text.startswith('foo')]
```

Watch it in action:

```
s = """<root>
    <parent>
        <child>foo987654</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>bar15245</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>baz87742</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child>foo123456</child>
    </parent>
</root>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(s)
elems = [elem for elem in root.findall('parent') if elem.find('child').text.startswith('foo')]
```

Checking the data:

```
for elem in elems:
    print elem.find('child').text
>>>
foo987654
foo123456
```

Comment: NINJA!  i'm assuming this would be case sensitive, yes?

Comment: @Brad XML is indeed case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [`xml.etree` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax), this library doesn't support the `contains()` operator from XPath. My suggestion would be to select all children with the XPath `/parent` and then iterating on each result to remove children's content that do not start with *foo*.

Comment: Is there a pure xpath solution without having to do extra iterations and removing nodes?

Comment: Using xml.etree? Sure doesn't look like it.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) library if you want to accomplish that using a pure XPath expression, without any other operation.

Answer (score 0):

with xpath

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(s)
for e in doc.xpath(".//child[starts-with(text(), 'foo')]"):
    print e.text
```